# What is the components of a non static website and related skills

Tags: web-services, web

I am new to the IT area and want to create my own site. I know a lot IT skills(SQL, basic JAVA, Python etc) but lack of the full pictures of a website.

The components I know are:

front end: what ever people see, ( HTML, JS, CSS,)

back end: The server, the database, the application (one kind of coding language, SQL) and an API to connect the back and front end (I am not sure what kind of skill I need in here, maybe TOMCAT or something)

Besides,I need a domain.

That is all I know.. I just want to have a full pictures of a non static website.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your skillset, you are already very close to creating a dynamic (non-static) website.

1. With HTML/JS/CSS you can create a purely static website. This is the UI.
2. With Database manipulation languages like SQL, you can modify the content in databases. This is the database.

So what you are missing right now, is a way to connect the two (UI and Database) - and that is where a server side language can come in handy.

I suggest playing around with a simple server-side languages (PHP,  for example) to get started.